# Publish application and include .dbo and tables?

Tags: c#, deployment

I am trying to publish my Windows forms application which uses a data connection (.dbo) for tables that run my application. However, when I publish the application, I get errors saying the application cannot access the SQL database.

I have looked through YouTube videos and read on the Windows website but I cannot really find anything that solves my problem. The server is a local server named after my laptop name. All of them talk about .mdf databases but I can only see a .dbo under data connections which includes all the tables I created for my application.

I get the following error:

> "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application...
>
> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection. (provider: Named Pipes Provider. error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

It works fine when I run the .exe file on my computer where I built the application but the above error is given when I run the application on another computer.

Can anybody help me publish my application to include the .dbo and all tables?

Comment: Publishing an application and a database instance are two different things. You will need to have a server running an instance of the DB and make sure your connection strings are pointing to that server / instance. Depending on your use case, you might be able to use a free edition. In any case, the server where the DB resides needs to allow inbound connections from wherever you are running the application.

Comment: If you are using visual studio and have the database as a project in your solution, you can right click the db project and 'Publish" it to a shared server.  Then make sure your application has the connection string to that db on that server, and re publish the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answers DrDoomPDX and BattlFrog. So if i understood you correctly, the first thing i need to do is get server space for a db. Yes, I am using visual studio so then i have to publish my project to that server space. Change the connection string to the live server and then republish it.

Comment: BattlFrog, my tables are under server explorer inside a .dbo Data Connection.